# Show direction of two location in google map V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show Direction betwwn two location in Google map.

I am using api of Google map:

```
URL for US Cities:  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?waypoints=optimize:true|40.722543,-73.998585||40.7064,-74.0094|&sensor=false

URL for INDIA Cities: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?waypoints=optimize:true|22.7,-72.87||22.3,-73.2003|23.0379814,72.5118121&sensor=false
```

Api gives result for US but not for India,

I search to show direction but i get code related to this  api,

If any one have any other option for Showing direction then please tell me.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried by adding region parameter in your URL ? region=in for india and for US region=us

Answer (score 0):

Your first 2 points are pointing to the Atlantic Ocean. No surprise you get no results :-)

Perhaps you meant:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?waypoints=optimize:true|22.7,72.87||23.0379814,72.5118121|&sensor=false
```

Comment: In google i found this lat long of India's two city.

Comment: @user3916943 I don't know how you got those, but they're incorrect. Use [this tool](http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html) to find correct coordinates.

Comment: @user3916943 Your link had a negative longitude while all of the cities listed in that link have a positive longitude :-)

Answer (score 0):

To show directions on your `Google Maps API V2` you can use this guide I wrote exactly on this topic:

[Google Maps API V2: Draw Driving Directions Guide](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822)

Now in case you don't get any result from the `Google Directions API`, the reason for this is probably that there is now roaded way to reach from your first location to the second.

And that the reason you are getting:

```
"status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
```

in your result, so check again the coordinates you are specifying for your call.